# Bash Brace Expansion & Variables

Tags: bash, variable-substitution, brace-expansion

I have a find command:

```
find Directory/{Alpha,Bravo,Charlie} arg1 arg2
```

I want to replace `Alpha,Bravo,Charlie` with `$find_dir`

```
find Directory/{$find_dir} arg1 arg2
```

however the latter expands to

```
find Directory/{Alpha,Bravo,Charlie} arg1 arg2
```

rather then

```
find Directory/Alpha Directory/Bravo Directory/Charlie arg1 arg2
```

Why? It's part of a fairly complex bash script that may have more or less directories, not all which are relevant (so globbing Upload/* would not work). So if I setup three now and add another, I'll have to manually add it in later. Plus I need it run from the root of directories to keep finds outputs perspective (./Upload/Dir/file as opposed to ./Dir/file).

But using a variable would permit me to change that as needed and keep it relevant to other parts of the script.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From `bash` documentation, [Brace Expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) section:

> **Brace expansion is performed before any other expansions, and any
>   characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result**. It
>   is strictly textual. Bash does not apply any syntactic interpretation
>   to the context of the expansion or the text between the braces. To
>   avoid conflicts with parameter expansion, the string ‘${’ is not
>   considered eligible for brace expansion.

Another note, in `bash`:

> The order of expansions is: brace expansion, tilde expansion,
>   parameter, variable, and arithmetic expansion and command substitution
>   **(done in a left-to-right fashion)**, word splitting, and filename
>   expansion.

So in your case, `bash` *saw* brace expansion before variable expansion, it will do brace expansion first, produce result `{Alpha,Bravo,Charlie}`.

If you can control `$find_dir` variable content, you can use `eval`:

```
eval "find Directory/{$find_dir} arg1 arg2"
```

Comment: That did the ticket. it successfully evaluated and works fine. You changed your post and removed what I found most helpful to understanding the issue (although you reiterated it) --> The  order  of  expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic
       expansion, and command substitution; word splitting;  and  pathname  expansion.

Comment: @Miati: I think the documentation in brace expansion section is more concise, because it has `and any characters special to other expansions are preserved in the result`. For `The order of expansions is: brace expansion; tilde expansion, parameter and variable expansion, arithmetic expansion, and command substitution`, you missed the important thing, they are done from **left to right**. You can try `a=1; echo $a $((a++)) {0..$a}` and see the result. If brace expansion was done first, you must get `1 1 1`, but the result is `1 1 2`.

Comment: @Miati: Sorry for mistyping in above comment, must get `1 1 {0..1}`, but the result is `1 1 {0..2}`