# understand the order of operations for bash parameter expansion

Tags: bash

I read a similar example from bash programming book:

```
$ cat indirection 
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -x
num=1
eval "${!num#*:}"
$
```

When I execute the script with `bash indirection "test:echo blah"`, then how is the last line of the script processed? I guess first the indirection happens so that `eval "${!num#*:}"` becomes `eval "${1#*:}"`? Then substring removal takes place and `eval "${1#*:}"` becomes `eval echo blah`? If yes, then why is `eval` needed, i.e `${!num#*:}` instead of `eval "${!num#*:}"` would provide the same results?

Comment: Does https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164733/117549 help?

Comment: @JeffSchaller Sorry but Brace expansion is not what this question is about.

Comment: I am assuming that `num=1` is in fact `num=$1` according to your execute string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output of the parameter expansion is:

```
$ echo "${1#*:}"
echo blah
```

Well, yes, in this specific case:

```
$ set -- "test:echo blah"
$ eval "${1#*:}"
blah

$ ${1#*:}
blah
```

Execute the same command. But that is not always true:

```
$ "${1#*:}"
bash: echo blah: command not found
```

In fact, an string that contains shell meta characters will not work correctly even if unquoted.

```
$ set -- "test:echo blah > file"
${1#*:}
blah > file
```

The redirection did not happen, but (beware that a file will be created):

```
$ eval "${1#*:}"
```

Will create a file called file in the PWD.