# It's possibile to delete some file with a range af number in a name?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, camera

I have many images captured from my webcam and their name are:

```
2021-03-29_06-00
2021-03-29_06-02
2021-03-29_06-04
2021-03-29_06-06

2021-03-29_07-00

2021-03-29_08-00

2021-03-29_09-00
etc..
```

I want to delete images shooted by night.

I found script to obtain sunrise (and sunset) times, now I have to filter my files and delete.

I start to try with **ls command**.

If I use:

```
ls *_{00..06}*.jpg
```

the result is correct.

By if I insert a variable with the time of sunrise, encounter of problems.

```
SUNRISE="06"
ls *_{00..$SUNRISE}*.jpg
```

But the result are:

```
ls: cannot access '*_{00..06}.jpg': File or directory does not exist
```

Comment: Your problem lies with the order of expansions in `bash`, brace expansion is done BEFORE the variable is evaluated. Maybe [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/164733/123460) will help?

Comment: [How can I use $variable in a shell brace expansion of a sequence?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/7738/170373)